# What device should I use to test the iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am Android dev and I am planing to do some development for iphone/ipad devices. I know that you can use xcode emulator but it doesn't support some libraries and obviously the app has to be tested on real device before submitting it to the store. I am thinking about getting the iPad as I don't need another phone. Do you think guys this is a good idea?

Comment: TestFlight might help you when you are distributing a beta application. You can also leverage friends and family to help you out if you want to test on another type of device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always test your app on a physical device. Really.

As suggested, get a single device for your primary testing and rely on beta testers using a wider range of devices to get coverage.

iPad seems like a sensible choice. It has most features from the other devices: gyro, camera, location, et cetera.

TestFlight is awesome for beta testing.

I hope you'll have fun with iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends. Ask yourself are you going to write only phone applications or both iPad and iPhone applications?

Apple does sell the iPod touch if you don't want to get a full iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy iPad 2 with 3g or iPad 3 with 4g because they support gps tracking (they have gps). But if your apps wouldn't use gps tracking you can both iPad 2 wifi or iPad 3 wifi (they has cameras) if you want to develop photo apps. For other types of apps you can use iPod touch 4g.
So I think new iPad 3 will be a good)) for develop and personal use.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also important to make sure you test on both retina display and non retina display - thats the main difference that you should pay attention to in my mind. Bear in mind that you will need two sets of art work for both resolutions.